# Escape awk command in ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, awk

I have the following command;

```
su user1 -c "ssh user1@192.168.1.2 awk '$5\==1{print\$3}' filename.log" | uniq -c
```

Running the command gives the error:

```
awk: ==1{print
awk: ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: ==1{print
awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I have tried several escaping methods with no luck. Any advice will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for this:

```
su user1 -c "ssh user1@192.168.1.2 \"awk '\\\$5==1{print \\\$3}' filename.log\"" | uniq -c
                                   ^^                                    ^^
```

Basically, first of all you need to imagine how to execute the command if you are `user1`:

```
ssh user1@192.168.1.2 "awk '\\\$5==1{print \\\$3}' filename.log"
```

and then you introduce it into the `su user1 ...` escaping the quotes.

Comment: Would that not require using `\\\$` for the awk internal field specifiers?

Comment: You are completely right, @EtanReisner, I had tested but didn't notice it was wrong. Just updated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Escaping the right way is quite tricky. You could write like this:

```
su user1 -c 'ssh user1@192.168.1.2 awk \"\\\$5 == 1 {print \\\$3}\" filename.log' | uniq -c
```

or like this:

```
su user1 -c "ssh user1@192.168.1.2 awk \'\\\$5 == 1 {print \\\$3}\' filename.log" | uniq -c
```

That is, you need to escape the quotes *and* the `$` signs within the quoted string. Since the `$` signs always need to be escaped, you need to double-escape it in this case, that's why the `\\\`.